# angular: httpClient.get from resolved Promise fails from test

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-test

I'm having a hard time writing a test for a service which does a call to angular's `httpClient.get(...)` from inside the `then` of a resolved promise. Inside of the whole app (i.e. not the test) everything is working as expected, the promises get resolved and from the resolved promise's data the URL is extracted for the `httpClient.get` call

However in the test even though the promise is resolved (the `then(...)` is executed) the `httpClient.get(...)` is never executed apparently.

To illustrate the problem I created a snipped based on angular's Http Guide Testing. See the whole thing here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y21e6j

The test with the promise is failing with:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL:
>   api/heroes", found none.

In general I have two functions:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<any> {
    const sub = new Subject();
    this.http.get<any>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      ).subscribe(data => sub.next(data));
    return sub;
  }


  notWorking(): Observable<any> {
    const sub = new Subject();
    const promise = Promise.resolve([this.heroesUrl]);
    promise.then(url => {
      console.log('Promise is resolved');
      this.http.get<any>(url[0])
        .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
        ).subscribe(data => sub.next(data));
    })
    return sub;
  }
```

I also copied the tests from the angular guide and inserted one for the second method. They look like this:

```
it('should return expected heroes (called once)', () => {

  heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
    heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'should return expected heroes'),
    fail
  );

  // HeroService should have made one request to GET heroes from expected URL
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(heroService.heroesUrl);
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // Respond with the mock heroes
  req.flush(expectedHeroes);
});

    it('should also work with promise', () => {

  heroService.notWorking().subscribe(
    heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'should return expected heroes'),
    fail
  );

  // HeroService should have made one request to GET heroes from expected URL
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(heroService.heroesUrl);
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // Respond with the mock heroes
  req.flush(expectedHeroes);
});
```

Notice that as soon as you remove the promise.then from the `notWorking()` the test succeeds again.

I currently cannot work around the additional subject created there, but this shouldnt influence the issue I have with the promise.

I also can't work around the promise, because it's returned from a 3rd party library. I tried wrapping it to a Observable (`fromPromise`) but this didnt help either.

See the whole thing here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y21e6j

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why do you create a subject  in `getHereos`? This looks like it could cause a memory leak while not having any advantages over not subscribing and returning the observable itself. The same goes for the `notWorking()` method. Also, what is the reason you use Promise.resolve at all in `notWorking()`. Maybe you can explain what you try to achieve, because it looks like it is not really required.

Comment: As for your question, I'm not 100% sure but I think your problem is that you check if the http request has been sent before it has been actually sent. You need to put your assertions (expect) in the subscribe callback, where you also check that the returned heroes match your expectedHeroes

Comment: Ah wait, I think you can just move your `req.flush` statement above your expectations (above the `Hero service should have made one request...` comment.

Comment: related to your question why I'm doing it: there's more happening then just the code you see. I only took out the relevant parts to illustrate my problem...

Moving the req.flush does not work...

Comment: have you tried moving the assertion into the subscribe block?

Comment: In your code you are basically making a cold observable hot, that means if you have a late subscriber it won't get any of the previous emitted values. Read more in this [article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with some help I found the issue... According to https://www.joshmorony.com/testing-asynchronous-code-with-fakeasync-in-angular `fakeAsync()` along with `flushMicroTasks()` needs to be used... And indeed it does work:

```
it('should also work with promise and fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {

      heroService.notWorking().subscribe(
        heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'should return expected heroes'),
        fail
      );
      flushMicrotasks();

      // HeroService should have made one request to GET heroes from expected URL
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(heroService.heroesUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

      // Respond with the mock heroes
      req.flush(expectedHeroes);
    }));
```